# Java Battleships Issues

Tags: java, swing

I have to design a batleships game for friday but the course im doing seems to have skipped a few things because although i managed all the other assignments this final project is unbelievably above my grasp but i have to do something.

i have the following GUI code which gives me my playing grids but i have absolutely *no idea* how to do the following things

1. assign a ship to some cells - and color these cells to reflect this
2. how to do the actual hit,miss,sunk and update the grid

i figure if i can at least do these i can duplicate the code for the cpu but im sooooooo stuck so any help is really appreciated please guys work some magic :)

```
/**
 * BattleGui: 
 * 
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BattleGui implements ActionListener 
{
    // Default filename to use for saving and loading files
    // Possible improvement: replace with a FileChooser
    private final static String DEFAULT_FILENAME = "battlegui.txt";
    private int GRID_SIZE = 8;
    private JButton [] buttonArray; 

    public JMenuBar createMenu() 
    {
        JMenuBar menuBar  = new JMenuBar();;
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Battle Menu");
        JMenuItem menuItem;

        menuBar.add(menu);

        // A group of JMenuItems. You can create other menu items here if desired
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("New Game");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Load Game");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Save Game");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(menuItem);        

        //a submenu
        menu.addSeparator();
        return menuBar;
    }

    public  Container createContentPaneCPU() 
    {
        int numButtons = GRID_SIZE * GRID_SIZE;
        JPanel grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(GRID_SIZE,GRID_SIZE));
        buttonArray = new JButton[numButtons];


        for (int i=0; i<numButtons; i++)
        {
            buttonArray[i] = new JButton(" ");

            // This label is used to identify which button was clicked in the action listener
            buttonArray[i].setActionCommand("" + i); // String "0", "1" etc.
            buttonArray[i].addActionListener(this);
            grid.add(buttonArray[i]);

        }
        return grid;
    }

    public  Container createContentPane() 
    {
        int numButtons = GRID_SIZE * GRID_SIZE;
        JPanel grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(GRID_SIZE,GRID_SIZE));
        buttonArray = new JButton[numButtons];

        for (int i=0; i<numButtons; i++)
        {
            buttonArray[i] = new JButton(" ");

            // This label is used to identify which button was clicked in the action listener
            //buttonArray[i].setActionCommand("" + i); // String "0", "1" etc.
           // buttonArray[i].addActionListener(this);
            grid.add(buttonArray[i]);
        }
        return grid;
    }    

    /**
     * This method handles events from the Menu and the board.
     *
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        String classname = getClassName(e.getSource());
        JComponent component = (JComponent)(e.getSource());

        if (classname.equals("JMenuItem"))
        {
            JMenuItem menusource = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());
            String menutext  = menusource.getText();

            // Determine which menu option was chosen
            if (menutext.equals("Load Game"))
            {
                /* BATTLEGUI    Add your code here to handle Load Game **********/
                LoadGame();
            }
            else if (menutext.equals("Save Game"))
            {
                /* BATTLEGUI    Add your code here to handle Save Game **********/
                SaveGame();
            }
            else if (menutext.equals("New Game"))
            {
                /* BATTLEGUI    Add your code here to handle Save Game **********/
                NewGame();
            }
        }
        // Handle the event from the user clicking on a command button
        else if (classname.equals("JButton"))
        {
            JButton button = (JButton)(e.getSource());
            int bnum = Integer.parseInt(button.getActionCommand());
            int row = bnum / GRID_SIZE;
            int col = bnum % GRID_SIZE;
            System.out.println(e.getSource());

            /* BATTLEGUI    Add your code here to handle user clicking on the grid ***********/
            button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            fireShot(row, col);
        }  
    }



    /**
     *  Returns the class name
     */
    protected String getClassName(Object o) 
    {
        String classString = o.getClass().getName();
        int dotIndex = classString.lastIndexOf(".");
        return classString.substring(dotIndex+1);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.
     * For thread safety, this method should be invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() 
    {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Battleships");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        int maxGap = 20;
        int ButtonWidth = 20;
        int ButtonHeight = 1;


        BattleGui battlegui = new BattleGui();
        frame.setJMenuBar(battlegui.createMenu());
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2,20,5));
        gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        //Set up components preferred size
        JButton b = new JButton("Just fake button");
        Dimension buttonSize = b.getPreferredSize();

        gui.add(new JButton("Player"));
        gui.add(new JButton("CPU"));
         b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight));
        gui.add(battlegui.createContentPane());
        gui.add(battlegui.createContentPaneCPU());
        frame.setContentPane(gui);
        // Create and set up the content pane.
        /*
        BattleGui battlegui = new BattleGui();
        frame.setJMenuBar(battlegui.createMenu());
        frame.setContentPane(battlegui.createContentPane());
        */

        // Display the window, setting the size
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Sets a Gui grid square at row, col to display a character
     */
    public boolean setGuiSquare(int row, int col, char c)
    {
        int bnum = row * GRID_SIZE + col;
        if (bnum >= (GRID_SIZE*GRID_SIZE))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            buttonArray[bnum].setText(Character.toString(c));
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * This is a standard main function for a Java GUI
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {

                createAndShowGUI();
                //Deploy();
            }
        });
    }

    //************************************************************************
    //*** BATTLEGUI: Modify the methods below to respond to Menu and Mouse click events

    /**
     * This method is called from the Menu event: New Game.
     * BATTLEGUI
     */
    public void NewGame()
    {
         System.out.println("New game selected");

    }


    /**
     * This method is called from the Menu event: Load Game.
     * BATTLEGUI
     */
    public void LoadGame()
    {
          System.out.println("Load game selected");
    }


    /**
     * This method is called from the Menu event: Save Game.
     * BATTLEGUI
     */
    public void SaveGame()
    {
          System.out.println("Save game selected");
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from the Mouse Click event.
     * BATTLEGUI
     */
    public void fireShot(int row, int col)
    {
          System.out.println("Fire shot selected: at (" + row + ", " + col + ")");
    }



}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400111/battleships-game-android-tutorial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest, take a step back and think about the problem domain.

You have a BattleScene, which contains BattleSquares. Each battleSquare can have atmost 1 ship, and can have a color. You also have Ship objects (which can belong to a particular player, indicates if it is damaged or not)...

BattleSquare needs to decide if it is a `Hit` or `Miss`, because it has all the information. It knows wether it has a ship or not.

```
/**true if had a ship, false if it was a miss
    */
public class BattleSquare{     
        public boolean processHit(){
             if (hasShip()){
                ship.setState(DESTROYED);
               return true;
             }
            return false;
        }
        public void setShip(Ship ship){ .... }
        public boolean hasShip() { ... } }   ... methods for color too
```

If you isolate your code into manageable snippets, where some classes represent the model, you will be able to manage things better. You appear to be mixing everything in one class and hence are feeling lost.

Similarly, your BattleScene will contains a `List` of BattleSquares. Once you fire, you can individuall seek a particular BattleSquare and tell it to process itself. If it is a hit, you update the state.

Idea is that your model classes only are responsible for managing state. Your controller classes can fire events, which are intercepted by views, who update the models and refresh themselves.

hopefully it helps.

Comment: its the actual cell selction thats really getting me here i can write the logic in and around but i've no idea how to select say cell row 1 column 2 and then colour it, that way i could deal with deploying the ships and also the actual playing of the game by selecting a color based on whether the coordinates appear in an array

Comment: you need to tell the model of the grid to colour itself. View will update it automatically. If it makes sense, perhaps use JTable. Write a TableModel, you can use a cell renderer to colour based on an attribute. There is a comprehensive tutorial available at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html. This is only if it makes sense to use table cells instead of the grid you are trying to make. I suspect for this assignment you could use it.